# How do you store user data - in one or multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I'm trying to store a user details (name, password, etc. ) in mongodb and I also wanted to store data on the books they've read (author, date, title), so this would be like an array of objects. Would it be better to store this in 2 different collections in the same database like this...

collection 1:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID('SOMEid'), 
    firstName:"x", 
    lastName:"y", 
    email:"x@z.com", 
    username:"xxx", 
    password:"xyz"
}
```

collection 2:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('SOMEOTHERid'), 
  spend: [objects containing each book they've read], 
  userID: 'SOMEid'
}
```

and then reference the user in the collection containing the book data.

or in 1 collection like this...

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('SOMEid'), 
  firstName:"x", 
  lastName:"y", 
  email:"x@z.com", 
  username:"xxx", 
  password:"xyz", 
  books: []
}
```

or is there another way to do it that's better. thanks

Comment: See this doc [Model Relationships Between Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/applications/data-models-relationships/) for some related info.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to save it in 2 different collections. You can get all the user meta sata from collection for login page etc. And other collection holds user actions like which all books user has read.
Are you thinking of using other DBs? Or Mongo Db is final?

Comment: Thanks. I'm probably just going to use mongodb, but I'm pretty new to backend development, so I don't really understand how the database works and how it's linked to servers and things like that

Comment: Cool. So better go ahead with 2 collections